# Storing a line read from text file to variable in Perl script

Tags: perl

I am looking for a solution to below case.

I need to read task.txt file from my Perl script disconnect.pl,
and I have to save the content of file to variable which I can use in multiple places in my Perl script.

Task.txt file contains words in single quotes separated by comma but in a single line like below

> 'qbc','456','sdf','fgh'

```
#########################
my $filename = 'testing_folder/text_document.txt';
open(FH, '<', $filename) or die $!;
while(<FH>){
$content=$_
}
print "$content"
my $ql = "select in ($content)";
print "$ql"
###############################
```

It's giving error at line `my $ql`

Comment: Just google "perl file tutorial" followed by "perl split tutorial".

Comment: Tried it.. ended up with errors

Answer (score 4):

I put your code into a file called "line" and tried to run it. Here's what happened:

```
$ perl line
syntax error at line line 8, near "my "
Execution of line aborted due to compilation errors.
```

As you say, line 8 is this line:

```
my $ql = "select in ($content)";
```

But here's a little secret about compiler error messages - they aren't as clever as we'd like them to be. And one common problem that you'll see is that they often report an error on the wrong line. So it's always worth checking the line or two before where the error is reported.

In this case, the problem is on the previous line:

```
print "$content"
```

Can you see it now? Take a close look at the end of that line. Do you see anything missing?

Perl statements are separated by semicolons. Newlines (usually) mean nothing to the Perl compiler. Perl is happy for you to spread a statement over two or more lines. So when it comes across a line without a semicolon at the end, it just assumes that the next line is a continuation of the same statement.

Which means that when you write:

```
print "$content"
my $ql = "select in ($content)";
```

Perl sees it as one statement:

```
print "$content" my $ql = "select in ($content)";
```

And that's a statement that doesn't make sense. So the compiler gives an error.

That also explains why the error reporting is a line out. Perl reports the error at the end of the problematic statement.

Oh. And in case I wasn't clear - you need a semicolon on the end of that line.

Comment: Thank you . Corrected it.

From the error am always thinking its problem with line my $ql = "select in ($content)";
didnt looked up into print statement above

Comment: @sravanisrinija: Well know you know the secrets of the debugging gurus and you'll look at the preceding line next time :-)